# Is it possible to pin a text on the top of the console c#

Tags: c#, text, interface, append, progress-bar

Hello I would like to add a text on the top of the console in c# That says something like (STATS: health="" Coins="", like a status bar) and it has to be pinned(I don't know if I am using the right verb). And I would like to do the same with  a switch menu(to see always the menu with options).

Thanks.

Comment: You can name the console window, failing that you write your own display that allows for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pin anything in a `Windows Console Application`.

---

I think what you try to achieve is done be clearing the console every time and redraw the screen.

An example for this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            counter++;
            DrawScreen(counter); 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    static void DrawScreen(int turn)
    {
        // Clear Console
        Console.Clear();
        // Draw Statusbar again on the 'top'
        Console.WriteLine("Current Turn: {0}", turn);

        // Draw additional stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I clear the console everytime?, by the way, thanks C:

Comment: @Varox Put a `simple turn example` in the update.